# Is there way give all users access to new form

Tags: permissions, access

I have a site and only Legal has access to the site. Is there a way to grant all users access to newform only and nothing else on the entire site? Please help me with the steps on how to set the permissions for this use case.

Comment: Can I please get some advice?

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint group is convenient option to provide access for multiple users at a time.

Create only permission : You will require to create custom permission level. below are the steps to create it.

1. On your SharePoint site, go to 'Site Settings'.
2. Click the 'Site Permissions' link (Under the 'Users and Permissions' section).
3. At the top of the page, click on the 'Permissions' tab.
4. Click the 'Permission Levels' button (In the 'Manage' group).
5. Click 'Add a Permission Level.'
6. Check the boxes for all Individual Permissions you want.
7. Create the group, and you're done!

For more details information please check the below links.

[Permission Level](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/how-to-create-and-edit-permission-levels?redirectSourcePath=%252fen-us%252farticle%252fHow-to-create-and-edit-Permission-Levels-53c86040-07fa-4ea7-bc55-34ee96b437fe)

Please mark as answer if you are satisfied.

Comment: i tried this and added "all users" to the group. I can't let anyone see the site at all. I only want to put a link to the new form on another site where user will input some data.

Comment: I thing this can be achieved by 'azure ad security group' that need to be applied on List level along with Custom Permission as mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly: go to https://forms.office.com/ and open the form in question. Click Share and select a sharing option.